# On the absolutely continuous sign measure functions and Borel $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider $X = [0, 1]$ with the Lebesgue measure and Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
Suppose $$ d\mu= gdm,~~ d\nu = hdm.$$  What are the necessary conditions on $g$ and $h$ so as to have $\nu$ absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu$.

I already know that  $\nu$ absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu$ if  $\nu(E)=0$ whenever $\mu(E)=0$.  Also,  $d\mu= gdm\Rightarrow \mu(E)=\int_Egdm$ and $d\nu = hdm\Rightarrow\nu(E)=\int_Ehdm$. So, I wanted to follow this with,

$\nu(E)=0$ whenever $\mu(E)=0\Rightarrow \int_Ehdm=0$ whenever $\int_Ehdm=0$.

My **question** is,  am I on the right track?  If yes/no, how can I proceed?

Comment: If $g \equiv 0$ on $E$ with $m(E) > 0$, then what value must $h$ have a.e. on $E$?

Answer (score 1):

With $\mu$ and $\nu$ as you specify, $\nu\ll\mu$ if and only if $m(\{x: g(x)=0<h(x)\})=0$.